# yeoman fullstack generator social oauth issue

Tags: mysql, mariadb, google-authentication, facebook-authentication, yeoman-generator

i am facing the OAUTH issue when i assign datatype JSON to facebook and google (that is by default in generator) . My database is mysqL AND I getting this error :

```
Server failed to start due to error: SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON,twitterJSON,googleJSON
```

if i set datatype : text or string then it works but i cant query on mysql then. This error is about mariadb but i am using mySql strange!

How to store in JSON datatype in MySql because i have to query on in like finding **facebook.id** etc?

refrence : https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2510

Comment: Your database is mariadb, not MySQL. They are very similar, but not the same. It would be a lot simpler if you could share the full sql statement with us.

Comment: ya but i am using mySql as database

Comment: No, you are not. Check out the error message: "check the manual that corresponds to your **MariaDB** server version"

Comment: exactly what confuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Type JSON issue**

MySql 5.7 support the type JSON.
[image]
[image]

But the issue is you are using sequelize. sequelize is a ORM for node.js
sequelize didn't support type JSON with MySql only support JSON with Postgres 
also see attachment.

[image]

***Recently confimed with their member***
[check here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7320)
[image]